# Input fields wont prepopulate with data after AJAX call .. sometimes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I implemented some jQuery syntax that makes an AJAX call to the server and pre-populates the inputs with the information that came from the server. This works but I recently came across a user who was unable to make the form work as intended. The Ajax call does not seem to fail they just stay as read only and their inputs are left blank.

I am stuck.

Here is part of the HTML code. They show the Input fields that are supposed to be updated via AJAX call.

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <label for="form-date" class="form-label">Fleetwood Order # <span class="astrisk">&#42</span></label>
        <input type="text" minlength="6" maxlength="6" id="order-number" name="order-number" class="form-control" required>
        <span id="incorrect-quote" class="invalid-feedback"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <label for="form-date " class="form-label">Job Name <span class="astrisk">&#42</span></label>
        <input tabindex="-1" id="job-name" type="text" name="job-name" class="form-control" readonly="readonly" required>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row mt-3">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <label for="form-date " class="form-label">Dealer Contact <span class="astrisk">&#42</span></label>
        <input type="text" id="dealer-contact" name="dealer-contact" class="form-control"  required readonly="readonly" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="form-email" class="form-label">Contact Email <span class="astrisk">&#42</span></label>
            <input type="email" id='email' name="email" class="form-control email" id="for-email" required readonly="readonly">
            <span  class="incorrect-email invalid-feedback"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the JavaScript code.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  const orderNum = $("#order-number");
  const jobName = $("#job-name");
  const dealerCntct = $("#dealer-contact");
  const email = $("#email");
  const contactPhone = $("#contact-phone");

  //Listen for keypress on order number input
  orderNum.bind("input propertychange", function () {
    $("#incorrect-quote").hide();

    const inputValue = orderNum.val();
    const lengthOfInput = inputValue.length;

    if (lengthOfInput === 6) {
      checkifNumbers(inputValue);
    }
    console.log(inputValue)
  });

  function checkifNumbers(input) {
    //make sure that the what is entered is digits only.
    if (!/^[0-9]+$/.test(input)) {
      alert("Please only enter numeric characters in this field");
    } else {
      input = input.trim();
      getQuote(input);
    }
  }
  //If input is all digits and the length of input is equal to six.
  //Send post request to PHP backend,
  async function getQuote(input) {
    try {
      const url = urlSelect.getQuoteUrl;
      let result = await $.ajax({
        url,
        type: "GET",
        data: {
          order: input,
        },
      });
      result = JSON.parse(result);

      if (result.length !== 0) {
        updateInputsVal(result);
        $("#incorrect-quote").text("");
        $('button[type=submit]').attr('disabled', false);
      } else {
        $("#incorrect-quote").text("Order does not exist!");
        $("#incorrect-quote").show("");
        $('button[type=submit]').attr('disabled', "disabled");

      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.log("Was not able to get quote data from the DB.");
      console.log(e.message);
      //create object with empy values and pass into our updateInput function
      removeReadOnly("err");
    }
  }
  // Update all inputs with the data that came back from the DB.
  function updateInputsVal(result) {
    console.log(result)
    jobName.val(result[0]["job_name"]);
    dealerCntct.val(result[0]["cust_contact"]);
    email.val(result[0]["cust_email"]);
    contactPhone.val(result[0]["cust_phone"]);
  
    //Remove read only property from element. 
    removeReadOnly();
  }
  //Remove read only attribute
  function removeReadOnly(err) {
    if (!err) {
      dealerCntct.attr("readonly", false);
      email.attr("readonly", false);
      contactPhone.attr("readonly", false);
    } else {
      console.log("this ran");
      jobName.attr("readonly", false);
      dealerCntct.attr("readonly", false);
      email.attr("readOnly", false);
      contactPhone.attr("readonly", false);
    }
  }

});
```

Comment: A few observations with your form html. Don't use hyphens in your input `name` attributes, use underscores instead. You got 2 `id` attributes in your email input. And make sure each label `for` attribute value matches the related input `id` attribute value.

Comment: follow the logic to determine what *must* be true for the inputs to remain readonly.